# PHPStorm keypair setup to use gitlab

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitlab, openssh

I just got a License for PhpStorm and I try to setup keypairs to can pull codes to Gitlab but I do not find where and how to make this? Where do I do this? The problem seems to be related that PhpStorm is not using root privileges.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I'm not entirely sure this is the most appropriate place to put this answer, I believe it is the most likely place others will end up at when facing issues trying to connect to GitLab via VCS for PHPStorm (or, really, any JetBrains IDE).

That being said, the issue I faced is very similar to the OP-- when running Git Bash, I had no issues at all connecting to Git Lab via SSH. However, when attempting a connection with PHPStorm's VCS via Git it would perpetually hang.

To precursor, my own findings are secluded to those of you **running JetBrain IDEs on Windows.**

---

### The solution is:

1. First you must (obviously) [have an SSH key created](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) and [registered for your GitLab user account](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/03/04/add-ssh-key-screencast/).
2. As [@Spero.ShiroPetto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302919/spero-shiropetto) has mentioned, PHPStorm does indeed utilize the standard $HOME/.ssh directory for SSH Keys. So:

   - Ensure your newly generated Key files are available from [your home directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory), inside the .ssh folder.
   - PHPStorm also uses the standard naming convention for these files, so for the sake of simplicity, keep these named as "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub".
3. **(OPTIONAL)** It would be good practice to also [create a config file](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files) for your SSH keys. This will help in the event you need to have multiple key's down the line. If you're using a non standard SSH port, or if there are other non standard parameters associated with the connection to the server, this really is a must.
4. Now, you're ready to open up PHPStorm but, before doing so, ensure you are running it as Administrator. This is necessary because when using VCS for Git, PHPStorm creates a batch file in your temp directory. This file must be writable for PHPStorm, and this is accomplished most simply by running the application as an Administrator.
5. Finally, before attempting to test/clone the repo from your GitLab server, you'll need to set Git to use it's built-in SSH executable when accessing Git. So:

   - open up the settings for PHPStorm (File->Settings or Ctrl+Alt+S)
   - Expand the Version Control section in the Project Settings and select Git
   - Ensure that the SSH-Executable is set to "Built-in". (While you're here, you might as well ensure that the Git executable is also set correctly. You can hit the Test button to verify this)

If like the OP and myself, you've been able to connect via Git Bash before, then at this point you should be able to connect and use VCS for your Git needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have o create a pair of keys on the shell. Therefore follow these [instructions](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/ssh.html). Then copy the content of the public key to your GitLab user account.

Comment: I have the Key Pairs but how do I add those to my project. At the beginning I had working but after restarting IDE doesn't work any more

Comment: You have to add the public key (extension `.pub`) to your GitLab user account. Therefore go to your profile, switch to `SSH keys` and add a new SSH key. Copy the content of the public key to this form.

Comment: I have that and I use with netbeans and it works on the same machine where PhpStorm is installed and case of Netbeans works. I bought this License because the extra Features are promising but I can clearly see how to manage this IDE.

Comment: I don't think you have to explicitly add the key to PHPStormer. I just tested this with PyCharm (the python version). It will use the systems settings of git and SSH. You only have to enable VCS from the menu.

Comment: When I try to push the codes to the repository I get pop up window which expects user credentials password. With SSH key enabled should be okay without password

Comment: I do everything from terminal! But the expected would be to use the IDE thats's why I bought this Stuff and between I experienced that all my code has gone when trying to merge codes.

Comment: Don't rely on a link that may go away any time. Please summarize the steps.

Comment: Welp, link went away.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Netbeans, so not sure if you are adding your private key directly into your IDE or not, but PHPStorm uses standard Git/SSH settings.

- What OS are you using?
- If Windows, when you installed Git (msysgit) did you choose OpenSSH or plink?

PHPStorm will utilize the standard `$HOME/.ssh` or `%userprofile%/.ssh` - You can store a single id_rsa key here or if you use multiple keys you can add the configuration to `%userprofile%/.ssh/config`.

There is a bit of information in the PHPStorm help files - http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-git-integration.html#d598046e253

If you are using `plink` on Windows, make sure you connect with `PuTTY` or `plink` first so that you can accept the server's host key..

```
plink git@gitlab.com:group/repo.git
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 b6:03:0e:39:97:9e:d0:e7:24:ce:a3:77:3e:01:42:09
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) y
Using username "git".
Server refused to allocate pty
Welcome to GitLab, User!
```

Depending on your setup, use `ssh-agent` or Pageant and add your key (`ssh-add` if using `ssh-agent`) so you are not prompted each time for your passphrase.

Your other alternative would be to connect over https and supply your credentials.